# How to create a fixed element

Tags: html, css

[image]

As you can see in the picture, how can I make the menu tab fixed one?

I tried changing the div positioning property to `fixed`, but the problem is that it gets overlaid on my picture. Actually the menu part gets to the screen when `tab1` is clicked.

I want to make the menu part fixed and while clicking on the menu contents , *that is : menu 1,2,3*, the right side content part should change.

I have uploaded my files here: [link](http://bbq.comli.com/demo/).

Comment: dont upload files .. use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) . and use the formatting box that stack over flow has .. so that ppl can read the question better .

Comment: Why is jQuery even tagged? :/

Comment: am sorry, am new here, will surely keep that in mind for my future posts and thanks j08691 for the editing ;)                                         @Terry i thought if jquery could help me to solve the problem

Comment: Do you mean that when you click the menu1(2,3) the website jumps to the top and you want to stop that from happening?

Comment: @TanelEero when user clicks menu1, the menu part should be fixed and the content part should jump acc.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
position: fixed
bottom: 54px; //Change to what you want
width: 100%; //Change to what you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my previous answer, you have two solutions:

Using CSS:

You can set a `margin-bottom` to the `.navigator` section manually such that the content is fully under this section, *but this is not a good solution unless this section will not change height anytime*.

Using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery):

You can give the `height` value to the `.navigator`using:

```
$(".navigator").css({ height: $(".size").height() });
```

Comment: thanks for the reponse, i tried giving height a value but the problem is that its shifting my home page pic by that value.. i have updated my files hosted, the problem is that the menu contents appear on top of my pic i dont want that to happen..

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. When you `position:fixed` you remove the element from the document flow, which is why it sits on top of your image.

You need to position it as well, for instance

```
.your-element{
position:fixed;
top:0; /* Positions top of your div to top of browser window*/
left:0; /*positions left of your div to left of the browser window*/
}
```

The above code will give you a fixed menu in the top-left corner of your window at all times. You can mess around with the margins to get it exactly where you want it.